# Selectively split a branch into two

Tags: git

I have a branch which contains a number of commits, namely c1, c2, c3, c4.

```
master --> c1 --> c2 --> c3 --> c4
```

I want to pick c1 and c3 to a new branch, while c2 and c4 stay in current branch.

The final log shall look like

```
master --> c1 --> c3
        \
         -> c2 --> c4
```

I know I can rebase a couple of times to achieve this, but is there a faster command to move a commit, or something like interactive rebase and put selected commits to another branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `master` in the graph is not clear. I just suppose it's the root commit `c0` of the branch.

1.cherry-pick

```
git checkout -b new1 c0
git cherry-pick c1 c3
git checkout -b new2 c0
git cherry-pick c2 c4
```

2.rebase

```
git rebase -i c0 c3
#======
pick c3
drop c2
pick c1
#======
git branch new1

git rebase -i c0 c4
#======
pick c4
drop c3
pick c2
drop c1
#======
git branch new2
```

`new1` is `c0-c1'-c3'` and `new2` is `c0-c2'-c4'`